# MATLAB: fscanf - retaining columnar structure

Tags: arrays, matlab, scanf

I'm trying to load a large text file into MATLAB. The file has the following format:

```
567.1   339.8   13923645.0  1.3 0.6
568.0   338.5   13923646.0  1.8 0.9
569.4   336.9   13923647.0  2.4 1.1
570.8   337.1   13923648.0  3.3 1.0
570.8   338.8   13923649.0  4.3 0.6
```

This is meant to be imported as a [:,5] array. However, I'm using the command:

```
inputData = fscanf(fid, '%g\t').';
```

This causes the numbers to imported as a one-dimensional vector:

```
inputData = [567.1 339.8 13923645.0 1.3 0.6 568.0 338.5 13923646.0 1.8 0.9 ... etc]
```

How do I get it to retain its 5 column structure?

Comment: Did you try simple `A = importdata(filename)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `load` command. It is the easiest in this case

```
   x = load('myFile.txt');
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302392/matlab-setting-many-variables-based-on-the-contents-of-a-row-array) where you are splitting out inputData later into 5 separate arrays, I would just read the text file into its 5 separate arrays from the beginning.

```
[x y currentSampleTime velocityX velocityY] = textread('data.txt','%f%f%f%f%f');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `reshape` function to create an x-by-5 matrix out of your row vector.

```
reshape(inputData, 5, []).'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only numeric data the easiest way will be to use [DLMREAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dlmread.html):

```
inputData = dlmread(filename,'\t');
```