# MATLAB: Setting many variables based on the contents of a row array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I'm trying to tidy up my code. I have an array with 5 columns, each of which is assigned to a variable. At present, I use:

```
x = inputData(i,1);
y = inputData(i,2);
currentSampleTime = inputData(i,3);
velocityX = inputData(i,4);
velocityY = inputData(i,5);
```

I thought I could tidy things up a bit by just doing the following:

```
[x y currentSampleTime velocityX velocityY] = inputData(i,:);
```

Apparently this does *not* work. I presume there must be an elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If inputData was a cell array then you could do this:

```
[x y currentSampleTime velocityX velocityY] = deal(inputData{i,:});
```

However, since you are indexing the row with the variable `i` can I assume that this is inside a `for` loop?

If so I would just do the following before the loop?

```
x = inputData(:,1);
y = inputData(:,2);
currentSampleTime = inputData(:,3);
velocityX = inputData(:,4);
velocityY = inputData(:,5);
```

Then just use `x(i)` `y(i)` etc inside of your loop.

... or depending on how `inputData` is generated try to create the necessary arrays when reading in or creating inputData.

Also, on a personal note I don't like using `i` as a variable in m-code because it can easily get confused with the imaginary number if not properly initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
wh = size(inputData);
temp = mat2cell(inputData,wh(1),ones(1,wh(2)));
[x,y,currentSampleTime,velocityX,velocityY] = deal(temp{:});
```